# Different responsiveness for SVG gradient and underlying image?

Tags: css, svg, gradient, responsive

I need to place a transparent gradient on an svg image such that the image fades to transparent from the center to the far right side (vertical gradient).

[image: Like this].

The parent element has `background-color: red;`

The catch is I need the gradient to respond to changes in the size of the parent element (like when the browser is resized) while maintaining its **proportions** with respect to the parent element, and continuing to fade the underlying image.

The underlying image must behave like `background-size: cover;` in CSS. I've found that `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` accomplishes that nicely but I don't want the gradient to behave in the same way. It must always take up the same percentage of the parent element size even when the size of the parent element changes. Like it might do if `preserveAspectratio="none"`, `width="100%"`, `height="100%"` on the gradient. I have tried that and it doesn't work.

The way I have it now the gradient becomes more and more hidden when you resize the browser window horizontally. Check it out here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Wcomp/pen/WLxbyd?editors=1000).

I tried separating the gradient into a separate svg thinking that it would establish a new viewport allowing me to insert `preserveAspectratio="none"` which would stretch the gradient to fit the parent element size but that didn't work either.

Here is another way to think about it: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Wcomp/pen/aPBzLK?editors=1000). I want to combine the background behavior of the top example with the gradient behavior of the bottom example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the color cover into the div wrapper via a filter and accomplish what you want. Note that this specific implementation doesn't work on Firefox because it doesn't support fragment references in feImage. You can make this Firefox compatible by converting my filled rect into a self-contained data URI/svg+xml for feImage (which Firefox does support).

```html
<div id="main" style="filter: url(#half-cover);">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="361.42084mm" 
     height="74.083336mm" 
     viewBox="0 0 361.42083 74.083337" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
     id="svg1">

  <defs>
    
   <linearGradient id="linearGradient33" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"  x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" id="stop1159" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset="70%" id="stop1159" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset="100%" id="stop1161" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  
    <rect id="rectONE" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#linearGradient33)"/>
    
    <filter id="half-cover" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feImage x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="200%" xlink:href="#rectONE"/>
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  
  
  <image y="1.4210855e-014" 
         x="1.4210855e-014"
         preserveAspectRatio="none" 
         height="74.083336" 
         width="361.42084" 
         fill="#fff" 
         xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABVYAAAEYCAYAAAC3JK0dAAAZgUlEQVR4nO3dT48kR5kH4Mjs6mH+ iBVeDvhiWVgIs4I9APIKCa1YceQLcOUrIO4gcUMcLe6IzzAXC8lgrYw4sMDBQgvLYht5JST8hxl7 PJjuqtxDV2RFZmV311vT3VlZ9TwSmpns6qo3IyIj3/z1eKj+8Ic/NGliTk9P147NZrMRKnly3/ve 9zp/bpom/ftXv3otnzU0bnfu3LmWz4L/+PrXxy5hEr773e+uHSv3ANct1+Hx48drx8a+j/7nq6+u Hbuu++FV2Kde5CZtu6cNrY/vf//7V1LT1Fx23zgk//Txj6cvvfDC2GVM3lWvqSallJoNHzGrKlVb f9L1OLf+qmqPV9U4VTfnjGtVValJaefG8qpdtLbynJTjkF+56biM2YtEa42+73lret/XzFUqe5i8 Vsoe5pDuxbv4LDGWpmnS7Pj4eOw6wqZY83lOTk5u7LOGFvpNfj6HZZ+u0+s0FDKUXLdch11sfC67 FnbNLo7hFGy7pw018IdqaCwO9b4wn8/1G1fgqvffKqWzEHKiLqx/5PO6KNCd7ohvbpO1VZ3z+02M 2Ytc1/y17zvha3JXDPUw5T35kO7F+uCVqqpSPXYRAAAAUVXtUQYAGJduBAAAAAAgSLAKAAAAABAk WAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoAAAAAQJBgFQAAAAAgSLAK AAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoAAAAAQJBgFQAA AAAgSLAKAAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoAAAAA QJBgFQAAAAAgSLAKAAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAg wSoAAAAAQJBgFQAAAAAgSLAKAAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJV AAAAAIAgwSoAAAAAQJBgFQAAAAAgSLAKAAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAA AAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoAAAAAQJBgFQAAAAAgSLAKAAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAA AIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoAAAAAQJBgFQAAAAAgSLAKAAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAE CVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoAAAAAQJBgFQAAAAAgSLAKAAAAABA0u3Pnztg10DOb zcYuYU3TNGmxWKSmacYuhYmwt2zPHgAAl5vNZvqNa6IXAYDNzF577bWxa6Dn7bffHruEjrqu02w2 S/fu3Ru7FCbE3rI9ewAAXO7tt9/Wb1wTvQgAbGb24osvjl3DQTs+Pl479l+/+c0IlZzv1vFxunv3 bnru059OTz311NjlMBH2ls3YAwBgO7/59a/TSz/96dhlTJ5eBAC2Nxu6kTKuut6tf/r2dD5PDx4+ TP/zxz+mf3vhhbHLYSLsLduzBwDA5eq61m9cE70IAGxmt+6Y7KyqqtIHjx6NXQYwEnsAADAmvQgA u2h2eno6dg0Hbegfhv/73/8+QiXrbt++3flzVVUjVcIU2Vs2Yw8AgO0smka/cQX0IgCwvZl/o2Zc 77///tqxz3zmMyNUsu6tt94auwQmzN6yGXsAAGzn9sc+pt+4AnoRANje7IUvf3nsGg7ayz//+dqx b3/72zdfyIDvfOc7Y5fAhNlbNmMPAIDtPP2pT6WnPvnJscuYPL0IAGxv1jTN2DXQY07YB9bx9owd AGzGPfN6GFcA2Mz6P6jD6DQycNjsAQDAmPQiALCZeuwCAAAAAACmRrAKAAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKs AgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoAAAAAQJBgFQAAAAAgSLAKAAAAABAkWAUA AAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoAAAAAQJBgFQAAAAAgSLAKAAAA ABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoAAAAAQJBgFQAAAAAg SLAKAAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoAAAAAQJBg FQAAAAAgSLAKAAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAAAIAgwSoA AAAAQJBgFQAAAAAgSLAKAAAAABAkWAUAAAAACBKsAgAAAAAECVYBAAAAAIIEqwAAAAAAQYJVAAAA AIAgwSoAAAAAQJBgFQAAAAAgaDZ2AcB26rpOdV2nauxCznFyejp2CbDXdn0PuArHM20K57t79+7Y JeyMQ71WZgd63rAr9CKwYq0cLjMPE/Xe3/6W3nnnnXRycjJ2KYOe/+xnxy4B9tqu7wFX4bXf/W7s EthhP/nJT8YuYWcc6rXy3rvvpq985StjlwEHSy8CK9bK4RKswgS988476U9vvJHef/gwnc7nY5cz SLAK12cKe0DU8fHx2rE3//znESphFw2tj5dffnmESsZ37969tWOHeq08+uCDsUuAg6UX4ZBZK5QE qzBBr7/5Znrw4EGq63pwUwf226HsAft8bjy5oYDxULlWgJumF4Eua+VwCVZhgh4+fJiOjo7GLgMY iT0AABiTXgTgjGAVJqiq1v+J+H3+t42Arn3cA4Z+yv/o0aMRKmEXDf3t1Kmv+W25VoBdoBdhW/fu 3bNW2CuCVdgT//L882OXAIxo6nvAH//0p7Vj3/zmN0eohF10//79tWNTX/Pbcq2s/O2998YuAShM fV+2v96M+/fvWyvsFcEq7Innnntu7BI6pv5TSJiaXdsDooYa1G984xsjVMIuGgpWp77mt+VaWfm/ t95Kv3j11bHLAJamvi/bX2/G/fv3rRX2imAV9oQgEw7bPu4B/pMqLrKPa35brhVgF+zjvmx/vR7W CvukHrsAAAAAAICpEawCAAAAAAQJVgEAAAAAggSrAAAAAABBglUAAAAAgCDBKgAAAABAkGAVAAAA ACBIsAoAAAAAECRYBQAAAAAIEqwCAAAAAAQJVgEAAAAAggSrAAAAAABBglUAAAAAgCDBKgAAAABA kGAVAAAAACBIsAoAAAAAECRYBQAAAAAIEqwCAAAAAAQJVgEAAAAAggSrAAAAAABBglUAAAAAgCDB KgAAAABAkGAVAAAAACBIsAoAAAAAECRYBQAAAAAIEqwCAAAAAAQJVgEAAAAAggSrAAAAAABBglUA AAAAgCDBKgAAAABAkGAVAAAAACBIsAoAAAAAECRYBQAAAAAIEqwCAAAAAAQJVgEAAAAAggSrAAAA AABBglUAAAAAgCDBKgAAAABAkGAVAAAAACBIsAoAAAAAECRYBQAAAAAIEqwCAAAAAAQJVgEAAAAA ggSrAAAAAABBglUAAAAAgCDBKgAAAABAkGAVAAAAACBoNnYBAABDZjNtCgAwHr0Im7JWDpeZBwB2 0vvvvz92CQDAAdOLsClr5XAJVgGAnfSDH/xg7BIAgAOmF2FT1srhEqwCADvpwYMHY5fAjvCf1wEw Br3I1dvXe7q1crj2c0UDAJPSNE2qqqpzbF8bb55c0zRjlwDAntGLsClrhZKZBwBGd/fOnfTh48dj l8FE3L1zZ+wSANgzepGb0Q8kp8haoSRYBQBG97nnn0///fvfp4/+8Y+xS2HHfezWrfS5558fuwwA 9oxe5GYsFouxS3hi1golwSoAMLpPfOIT6Utf/KL/xJtLVVWVbt26NXYZAOwZvcjN+MUvfzl2CU/M WqEkWAUAdsLt27fT9P/jMK5bk/bjb7sAsHv0ImzKWiETrAIAO0FYBgCMSS/CpqwVsnrsAgAAAAAA pkawCgAAAAAQJFgFAAAAAAgSrAIAAAAABAlWAQAAAACCBKsAAAAAAEGCVQAAAACAIMEqAAAAAECQ YBUAAAAAIEiwCgAAAAAQJFgFAAAAAAgSrAIAAAAABAlWAQAAAACCBKsAAAAAAEGCVQAAAACAIMEq AAAAAECQYBUAAAAAIEiwCgAAAAAQJFgFAAAAAAgSrAIAAAAABAlWAQAAAACCBKsAAAAAAEGCVQAA AACAIMEqAAAAAECQYBUAAAAAIEiwCgAAAAAQJFgFAAAAAAgSrAIAAAAABAlWAQAAAACCBKsAAAAA AEGCVQAAAACAIMEqAAAAAECQYBUAAAAAIEiwCgAAAAAQJFgFAAAAAAgSrAIAAAAABAlWAQAAAACC BKsAAAAAAEGCVQAAAACAIMEqAAAAAECQYBUAAAAAIEiwCgAAAAAQJFgFAAAAAAiaXfaCuq7T0dHR TdTC0r1798Yu4VzHx8djl8A5zM3+sAewDXOzvaZp0nw+T03TjF0KEFDXtb3vmuhF2Ia52d6h9SLW yvYOba1MwYXBalVV6YNHj9LDhw/T6enpTdV08F566aWxSzjX62+8MXYJnMPc7A97ANswN9uZzWbp 1q1b6Z+femrsUoCgBw8f2vuuiV6EbZib7RxiL2KtbOcQ18oUVD968cVzY+6HDx+mN958M73z7rvp 5OTkJus6GEM/qfnwww9HqGTd3bt3145ZB7thaN2Ym2myB7ANe8DVOT4+Trdv306ffvbZ9PTTT49d DlzqZ6+8snbshz/84QiVjO+3v/1t+vGPfzx2GZOnF2EbepGrc2i9yM9eecVa2dKhrZWpuPBvrL7+ 5pvpr3/9q//M5oYNNRC7wjrYXeZmf9gD2Ia52U7TNOnx48fpf19/XYMKE+MZ5froRdiGudnOIfYi 1sp2DnGtTMGFweq7777r31cFAPZWVVUppZQ++uijkSsBAA6RXoRNWSu76dL/86q+R48eXUcdB2vo H4bflb8WP/RTJPO/G4bWjbmZJnsA27AHPLn+GOZGFZiOk5MTe98V0IuwDb3IkzvkXsRaiTnktTIF 4WD1a1/72nXUcbB+9atfrR175plnRqhk3V/+8pe1Y+Z/NwytG3MzTfYAtmEPeHJDYwhMyzPPPGPv uwJ6EbahF3lyh9yLWCsxh7xWpiAcrH7rW9+6hjIO19AF8q+f//wIlawbamTM/24YWjfmZprsAWzD HvDkNKgwfV/4whfSs88+O3YZk6cXYRt6kSd3yL2ItRJzyGtlCsLB6uPHj6+jDgqnp6djl3Au87+7 zM3+sAewDXMDHJqTkxN73zXRi7ANc8OmrBX2ST12AQAAAAAAUyNYBQAAAAAIEqwCAAAAAAQJVgEA AAAAggSrAAAAAABBglUAAAAAgCDBKgAAAABAkGAVAAAAACBIsAoAAAAAECRYBQAAAAAIEqwCAAAA AAQJVgEAAAAAggSrAAAAAABBglUAAAAAgCDBKgAAAABAkGAVAAAAACBIsAoAAAAAECRYBQAAAAAI EqwCAAAAAAQJVgEAAAAAggSrAAAAAABBglUAAAAAgCDBKgAAAABAkGAVAAAAACBIsAoAAAAAECRY BQAAAAAIEqwCAAAAAAQJVgEAAAAAggSrAAAAAABBglUAAAAAgCDBKgAAMDlVVY1dAgBw4GbHx8fn fvHOnTs3WMphGhrj2WzW+fNVNY2PHz++9LNKQ2vj5OTkSmrhyQzN23XMzenp6dqxTfcFa2UzF12D KQ3PwWXfc1Vuap0R96Rz8yTX9r4YOt+LeiKuRrQXYd2h7c0X7Venp6fxc2+as1+KQ22nva9B7fKc U1Wtfp+/lHb7GrzK9d4sz72c5Wb4pWsmG+IX892k7rl31nvThNf/RnOzxfsejKbZ6WvvOs1ms72+ b12HXVsrniVWmqZJ1Y9efHHtftKcfTU1+X/LF7c3o7w5Nk1aNE3nRlNV1dmGXR5bfTFVaf3GNOaN qjyvxWKRC2rPI9+A8jicfXl1/u3rU1r7/UXn1RTjmwZen8c8FWNeVdVaQ9QeH3j/RdO0tbTvl79v +etisTg7XlWpSWd/hbmu61WN59RfL1+fx6HJ66AYu6Hzumyum97NP+Uayoaw/5n5+8p1uVi0599U VTrqjV2TUmoWi+6YVlWqe7XWdX15zUU9ef6bou523fTq73z/8uvnfVY5Lvl71h4C8hicsz5u6jrr n3c75gNz26+9Xa9DTWBvXeX3WJRNcvF+VV6jA3PbesK12j/HzvF8TsVe0p5b/3zL710sVt+3nM8m FXtr8fr8PVVKqarr1K/4srnP1//QPlKu6/Y6Wx7rvz5fa1VVtXPXuW7Lz0wpVeWaWL5Xe+5ptW7b PaUco+X4tL8vPrddCwNrJde7KD4nf+2oqtLR0dFq3eVxW/6+3S/z15eflfeQzv6civ1x4Pz7Y7fN ddm/R6eU0nyxSM1y38s1dN67t8fn66ozLk2zuk6KuVx9cNO+rrz/18tzn8/ny5f1eoW0uuflMW0W i7M1W9fpqDfXeR9bpLO5GRrDzjXW+1quv/+dTbnuBsays36K78/3xPL9O/1RMe7lWK1dt8Vn5Brq uj5bL8W5tNdt75ru3GtS6rz/ougXFkU9+dpZ5LVa12evy19ffn4es1x7/uz+tVXq7EfFtZPX3rn3 s/wZxTyW97S8xtr1kse795lHdb26R5/TX3Z62OV+N18sOtd2s/xfvRyneXkNLeupqyrVR0ft/T31 zq/s11JKnd6hvxd0ziOP7bLOutd3VFXV9qb5c+fzeVvX2j5UvK5ejk/7+cU9N49d+74buHScy3kr xyat9pp+v3NZz1P+2v/eoR5xbc9Jy7WfVn1fU1WpTmd7Zt7DjvJ1UIxjfx4uU9bRH4+8BvO6z9dJ 2d9kl10/F9ZQ7g9Nc7YnL/fbpmlSqutUF2OxyGPYNOno6Kj97LwW54tFOy51Va366tTrPXr7bbnu Os9ZRa9Qrvt2beb3KdbQ2jPmJWNTPtOV496/1vJr2v4ij0++lxd7dF4PdV23Y3iTOmtreU6LxaJz LGv3gLRaD6fL86yLucpz3PZfqbhfXXIN9N+/3wuX+8DQNd95fe9+W753Zw8tzq19vi33vOWfy/nr 72z5a02xDoZWUv94eZ0O9RXt/TePZXFttGu7dw/on2f5jLIon09T6sxZHrf+uLbjVNyvO31gteqz 89ynuk5VcX3ma7n//qmor/PcXf5ajEc5voten5zPcigL6r93O77L/WttvyzWTznvQ/vE0Jpde69i fjq9WOA+UBq6J154v+1df0Pr7bzPaH9f1N6/Llcf080G+mPTWa8D12Y+vvacsYFOvUVt/d66/Oy6 rjcai6vWqSVttg7WYu+hh4V+w5gXcb5Aq3o9fOr8qd+IjTA4pbVGrZjUtpFvmtQMbS5p9aAytPCH BrtsLsrPWbvx5MU88DnlsXb8Uxq+ISybqc5FlZu48iZYbjzFxtK/QffPpXzQSCm1G3P5Pf0H+k3m e+3CTt2Lrqync2PNNZeBS1qNVW6A2jBloElrb175Qba/ZjepuVdDe+7ltTOwoa7dMPNLh16fbxrd IroPeUPndwOGHoSKQs6OpfJQt96ysUvFmJQNbOdBavn79tdy88+fkVJKORTpNTaD+9EWN7FLXtyp p9Te+Ir9dZEfYtKqAcxraK3x7dXbX6+Xrt1zXtM/p8575s8sGpj2Nbn5Kc67PPeyIS4byLWbVnHt lQ1/p+5ir2wf9Aau704NObBuitAoN72puPaHmsTl8U7TklJnbZV78tCNeOgct5HXXxs+FWO+WL3o 7P6Vz2f5IJjPOY9tfjDr34vyOJRzVhSwOud8aPk9dVW1D+p5jPIDRHvNVMsfdM1mqzWbx7G476be OikG8OyX8vcb3G8WRQ1D+3BKqRN0lA8RF4WpuemviroG76n5vfPetrxv5rCz00M068HUYM3N6sGl XJttH5PS+prtrfeqV1dKZ3NUNtdN06TFfN4JmFM6+yFJfw76127nYaI3N3lt5HNZFGsrr4FF6oYB /Xnf6AGq7HuWY7NomrN7y/L8m/k8zfPeuxyD/J5t2Ll8fTtHvfFd9M6vPfd8jabVD/D7fUa5r+U6 23CqN1b5mix/MNaO9bLWYjBWY9QLoTtjXeqt3XJO+/vZWg9UnHeue23OBl7Xf6/yWHtuvfFJvc9J 5fHyWi3GYJFWgdtiPm/D8nJvHLr2LzLUr5b7dNmjNdXwdZFD/GjP1umJyvWRztb06Xzeuc+lxSLN i++venOcx7TsQ/Layd+fqtWzUv7BTH+fLH/QM7Q28vc3qdh3i/to+dryOukc749FMd+pOfsBShnw pGKMFk2Tmvl8PeBbLFKazdoQuc5zU+yX2967tzF0Laz1v0t5Xxt63dFy/qpyf8g/sDn7Qnvfa8e5 /KFbr542oC7HPBX3/DK8S909INfRn5f23l+edx7v5X6XqrOwv/3asr9p76t5vyg+Z22+irXX2Qdz HeWYVqsfSPev8/LX9vwH6i772Cqt7gGdazbXk/eooodqe8o8h0XtzXLcyvHPv+a5zvPR7/U6/XBv D0lp9QwytF/310Fnz226wdhR/kF+fq/yntO7tvN79/OZdn7yD40H7rWd/aK3Hw3tkx0D19JaXxbQ WSvLmsp9v1xv/TwnEuJe9Dza+VPxeeV1mIq12fZ6zSpbyWsk7xFr62GLcWlrHtpbir1nbTxCn7Sd fp9a9rKpOHaR/wc8OgTXo7mNbgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>
  

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to mention that the gradient also has to be a mask. I'll actually be placing an image where the red is currently so it won't work to have the red colored stops. I'm going to study your answer though. I don't fully understand SVG filters yet. Is there a way that your solution would work if the gradient actually faded to transparent instead of to the color red?